# Wicket-Springboot Implementation

Tags: spring-boot, wicket

I have an application developed in the Wicket-Spring framework. I want to implement Dynamic Database routing using the `AbstractRoutingDataSource` API of Spring framework. I have developed small wrapper application in Sprinbgoot using `AbstractRoutingDataSource` which is working fine.

Now, my requirement is that I have to Integrate that Springboot solution in the existing Applicaiton 'Wicket-Spring'. After searching for Springboot support for Wicket. I got this link:https://dzone.com/articles/enhance-wicket-with-spring-boot. But, I am still not able to integrate my Solution developed in Springboot to the Wicket-Spring application.

Thanks in advance. Highly appreciate any guidance and direction on it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out https://github.com/MarcGiffing/wicket-spring-boot project.
You may use it to create a new application or as an inspiration how to glue Spring-Boot with Apache Wicket.